# How to determine startup run level for Ubuntu?

Tags: scripts, startup

We are planning to migrate from an older version of Ubuntu to (10.x) to the latest release of Amazon Linux. I'm trying to identify how to replicate the K and S scripts in the `rc0.d`, `rc1.d` etc directories.

My question is, how to determine which is the default level?

There is no `/etc/inittab`, and the man page says it's been replaced by files in `/etc/init`. But they `rcx.d` directories contains references to specific apps within our system, while the `/etc/init` contains a bunch of `.conf` files. I'm thinking this somehow points to the rcx.d directories, perhaps via the `rc.conf`, `rcS.conf` or `rc-sysinit.conf` but can't lock down the actual startup level.

Comment: Ubuntu uses Upstart now, so most of the old school scripts have been replaced with Upstart jobs (the .conf files you saw). Upstart still supports the old ways, so you can continue using the `rc` directories. To determine the current runlevel, use the `runlevel` command, the default is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has replaced the traditional SysV init with Upstart. To somewhat stay compatible with SysV or runlevel based init, Upstart still supports the SysV traditions.

You can find (and change) the default runlevel in the `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` file. The following command will do:

```
$ grep "env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL" /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf 
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
```

As you can see the default runlevel is 2, you can also change it to your desired runlevel.